# C# create derived record from base record instance

Tags: c#, record

Through the keyword `with` one can generate a new record with some or all of its properties set to the source's values.

Can we do something similar, but from a base record to another one that extends it?

```
public record class root {
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public record class extended : root {
    public string surname { get; set; }
}

//retrieve from root the shared properties
public extended from(root rt, string surname) {
    return //???
}

public example() {
    root rt = new root() { name = "jhon" };
    extended ext = from(root rt, "wick");
}
```

One could use reflection, or a custom constructor that takes `root` as a parameter, but i wonder if there is some record-specific shortcut

-EDIT- possible answer
record seems to implement a constructor that takes another instance of itself.
As such i can write:

```
protected extended(root original, string surname) : base(original) {
   this.Surname = surname;
}
```

avoiding the code repetition

Comment: You are trying to use composition but with `record`. The whole purpose of `record` is it to be immutable and improve readability. Trying to introduce composition which makes object debatably "mutable" and reducing readability defeat the original purpose of `record` IMO. You might as well just implement normal composition with readonly classes

Comment: They are templates for Json deserialization. So AFAIK they must have setters. I want two or more of this templates to be joined togheter and sent. As there are many templates i wanted to avoid an explicit mapping cuz it will take quite a bit and is error prone (i may forget one property, for example)

Comment: You don't need setters, you can use `get;init;` or constructor arguments

Answer (score 1):

You can go with copy constructors ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DRswKL)):

```
public record root (string name);
public record extended (string surname, string name) : root (name)
{
    public extended(root copy, string surname): this(surname, copy.name) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need reflection or a custom constructor, this is just a simple mapping:

```
public extended from(root rt, string surname) 
    => new extended {name = rt.name, surname = surname};
```

I'm not aware of anything specific to records that can be used to shorten the mapping code, though.